# How to Use Between Clause in Sql query without using and clause

Tags: sql, oracle, predicate, between

I have created a query which gets results between 2 dates, Its working fine..
Now i have a scenario in which users does not enter any date..In this case 
I need to fetch all the result from database regardless of date..
The following query fails when user does not enter any date, it returns 
empty result set.
Kindly guide me how to resolve this problem.

```
select * from emp_register
where date between ' 2015-03-26 15:42:52' and ' 2015-03-26 15:42:52' 
or status= 'Y'
```

Date Format is `Timestamp`

Comment: Mysql or sqlserver ? And what the datatype for `date` ?

Comment: **i have a scenario in which users does not enter any date** Does it works with another language than MySQL ?

Comment: date format is Timestamps..I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of options:

1. Using Dynamic SQL to build your queries based on user input
2. Using multiple IF/ELSE statements to build your query based on user input
3. Setting default values for start and end dates that would always fit in your time range, such as `1900-01-01` and `2300-01-01` if user didn't pass any.

Comment: Thank you, I would go with 3rd Option :)

Comment: It's probably easiest and most readable. However, I personally think 2nd one would perform better (from my own experience), especially if your data grows fast. Let me know if this works for you. :)

Comment: sure,I will let you know.. Thanks :)

Comment: No need to use PL/SQL, do it in SQL using **NVL**.

Comment: @LalitKumarB That's right. You can use **NVL** to replace NULL values or define default parameters in procedure description, such as `PROCEDURE P1 (Param1 IN NUMBER := 100);` So it's either users' input or default value. Up to personal taste or/and SQL standarts in your own company I guess.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas OP stated that he is using a query, which means he is doing it in pure SQL and not PL/SQL(i.e. any package/procedure).

Answer (score 2):

> where date between ' 2015-03-26 15:42:52' and ' 2015-03-26 15:42:52'

`' 2015-03-26 15:42:52'` is **NOT** a **DATE**, it is a **string**. Never ever rely on **implicit data type conversion**. You might just be lucky to get the result depending on your **NLS** settings, however, it will certainly fail when the client NLS settings will be different for others.

> Now i have a scenario in which users does not enter any date..In this case I need to fetch all the result from database regardless of date

No need to do in **PL/SQL**, do it in **SQL**.

Use **NVL** function on the values. Use a default **lower bound** and **upper bound** date values in the **BETWEEN** clause for the NVL.

For example,

```
SELECT *
FROM emp_register
WHERE DATE BETWEEN NVL(:date1, DATE '1900-01-01') AND NVL(:date2, DATE '9999-01-01')
OR status= 'Y'
```

So, whenever `:date1` and/or `:date2` and/is **NULL**, then it would use the default date values to fetch all the rows from the table.